# What value will return when I operate transform?.invoke() if transform is null in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was told that `invoke()` can be operated safely.

1:  What value will return when I operate `transform?.invoke()` in Code A?
     I think the Code  `val str = transform?.invoke(element) ?: element.toString()` is equivalent to the following code, right?

```
 val temp= transform?.invoke(element)
 val str=temp?: element.toString()
```

2:  I don't know whether `.let` is another choice in Code B, could you tell me?

**Code A**

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.joinToString(
        separator: String = ", ",
        prefix: String = "",
        postfix: String = "",
        transform: ((T) -> String)? = null
): String {
    val result = StringBuilder(prefix)

    for ((index, element) in this.withIndex()) {
        if (index > 0) result.append(separator)
        val str = transform?.invoke(element) ?: element.toString()
        result.append(str)
    }

    result.append(postfix)
    return result.toString()
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.joinToString(
        separator: String = ", ",
        prefix: String = "",
        postfix: String = "",
        transform: ((T) -> String)? = null
): String {
    val result = StringBuilder(prefix)

    for ((index, element) in this.withIndex()) {
        if (index > 0) result.append(separator)

        var str =element.toString()
        transform?.let{
           str=transform(element)
        }

       result.append(str)
    }

    result.append(postfix)
    return result.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?.` operator is called the [Safe Call Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

For `transform?.invoke(element)`, if `transform` is not `null` it'll call `invoke(element)` and return its value; otherwise it'll be `null` as well.

So yes, it's equivalent since if `temp` is not null `str` is `transform?.invoke(element)`, otherwise it's going to be `element.toString()`.

---

```
transform?.let{
   str = transform(element)
}
```

The compiler will assume that `transform` is not `null` in `let` block, since if `transform` is `null`, `let` block will not be executed because you safe-called. so Code B is also an equivalent of Code A.

---

Read more about null safety in Kotlin:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Also about Smart Casts:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts